# What is the difference between declaring a String and declaring it as final?

Tags: java, string

I know that Strings are immutable.

Then, what is the difference between:

```
String name ="Name";
final String name ="Name";
```

Why do we use `final` in this context? Because String is already immutable there seems to be no need. Second related question, why are String's `immutable`?. Other Data Types like int, boolean are not. If String is immutable does that make it thread-safe? I read that **"if String been mutable, a request to load "java.io.Writer" could have been changed to load "mil.vogoon.DiskErasingWriter""** `means` ?

Comment: Here the reference "name" is declared final, ie, it refers only to the string object "Name" and this reference cannot be made to refer to any other string object once it is declared final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here, but here are a few notes that should answer most of them:

- `final` means the variable can be assigned only once. It has nothing to do with mutability, which is a property of the object, rather than the variable (which is simply a handle)
- `String` is immutable, because you can't change its internal state (it has a `private char[] chars` that hold the characters). Primitives are also immutable. This is better visible in their wrapper equivalents - `Integer`, `Long` etc.
- yes, a String is thread-safe, because its state cannot be changed no matter how many threads work with it. Every operation on the string results in a new instance, rather than changing the existing one.

Comment: +1 For nice answer But what is maens by "if String been mutable, a request to load "java.io.Writer" could have been changed to load "mil.vogoon.DiskErasingWriter"

Comment: I have no idea what DiskErasingWriter is

Comment: Note that although you always get a new instance of String as a result of operations on String, they can sometimes be backed by the same array internally. `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz".substring(1,2)` will return a String with internal storage  for all 26 characters, rather than just 2. Solution is to do `new String("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz".substring(1,2))` which makes a copy of the relevant section of the underlying array resulting in the expected storage requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`final` means you cannot assign the variable a new value.

```
String name = "Name";
name = "MyName"; // legal

final String name = "Name";
name = "MyName"; // illegal, compiler error
```

Here is an article on why strings are immutable:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html

Comment: Specifically, the compiler will complain "cannot assign a value to final variable name"

Answer (score 2):

> I read that "if String been mutable, a request to load "java.io.Writer" could have been changed to load "mil.vogoon.DiskErasingWriter""

OK.  First thing to realize is that this is a **hypothetical** discussion.  String is not mutable.

So now imagine this piece of code:

```
public static final String CLASS_NAME = "java.io.Writer";

...

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(CLASS);
```

What class does this actually load?

If String's were mutable, some nefarious code running in the security sandbox would be able to mutate the *contents* of the String object that CLASS_NAME refers to.  In particular, it could change it from "java.io.Writer" to "mil.vogoon.DiskErasingWriter". The net result is that your application would be tricked into loading the wrong class.

By making String an immutable type (and one or two other things) this attack mechanism is foiled.

Answer (score 1):

Like William said :

> final means you cannot assign the variable a new value.

In addition, if you play with anonymous inner class like that :

```
final String mystring = "Hello";
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    void click() {
        System.out.println(mystring);
    }
});
```

The `mystring` object **must** be final.

Answer (score 1):

Its the difference between an object and its reference. A `final` variable can only be assigned a value once. This is true regardless of wether that variable refers to an immutable object or not.

Note that an 'immutable' object is itself typically (but not necessarily) composed of sets of `final` references.

Answer (score 0):

The other points have already been answered here, but you are still looking for an explaination to that quote you found:

> if String been mutable, a request to load "java.io.Writer" could have
>   been changed to load "mil.vogoon.DiskErasingWriter"

For reference, this appears to be from a different SO answer which is somewhat short and leaves out detail.

In general, if you write a public class that accepts mutable objects and stores them, or that returns a mutable object it is storing, the calling code can change that object from under the feet of that class.

For an example. Disclaimer: I don't know much about ClassLoader, so this is just for the sake of illustrating the problem. ClassLoader has a function `loadClass(String name)`. Imagine that method first checks if the class of that name is valid or trusted, and then loads it. Now if String was mutable, the calling code could change the class name from under the class loader's feet after it had already checked the class, and thus circumvent security measures.

Of course, if String was mutable, one could hope the implementation of ClassLoader would first make a *defensive copy* of the String. That way, the calling code has no chance of circumventing the security since it has no way to modify the contents of the *copy*. This is a general rule: Don't let calling code have any handle on mutable internal data of your class.

So String does *not* need to be immutable to ensure safe class loading. However, with immutable objects it is easier to ensure this kind of security, since they simply can't be changed from under you.